# Is framerate inversely proportional to video image quality?

Tags: video

I have screen recorded a several videos on my android phone, they take more than 128GiB of space, so I have decided to reduce the filesizes of the videos using ffmpeg.

I intend to minimize the filesize while keeping a reasonable perceived visual quality.

There are four important characteristics of videos: bitrate, framerate, resolution and duration.

Framerate tells how many frames are displayed per second, bitrate tells how many bits are needed to store one second of the video, resolution is the width and height of the frame in pixels.

I don't know much about videos, but if my math is good, filesize should equal to bitrate times length.

Image quality is hard to measure, but at fixed resolution, as a rule of thumb, the more bytes an individual pixel takes the better image quality, so it means larger filesize equals to better quality at fixed resolution.

Now assume resolution is fixed, the size of each frame can be calculated by bitrate divided by framerate, so the filesize of the frame is directly proportional to bitrate and inversely proportional to framerate, assume filesize is proportional to visual quality, this means framerate is inversely proportional to visual quality.

So, at fixed bitrate and fixed resolution, does increasing framerate actually decrease image quality? Is my reasoning right? I have tried to Google search the topic, but few results are relevant as per usual, and the ones are relevant give conflicting answers.

Comment: “So, at fixed bitrate and fixed resolution, does increasing framerate actually decrease image quality?” Unless the bitrate is adjusted to match frame rate, your assumption is right. But I also believe “quality” equates to how many keyframes are set per second I believe. More key frames = larger file size but also better quality. Someone with deeper experience should be able to clarify, but it is all a balancing act.

Comment: While you are correct, *in general* modern video compression relies on key frames and then delta frames that show the difference from one frame to the next. In theory a higher framerate could have less "differences" between frames and the compressor could, for some videos, potentially achieve better quality compression for a very similar bitrate with higher framerate. Higher framerates also result in smoother motion, which could be perceived as higher quality even when each individual frame is taking less data. Each individual frame might be "lower quality" but everything might "feel" better.

Comment: Resolution; one "perceived dot" (note: that might be several pixels in the image!) in a STILL image should be at MOST 1/30 degree of angle for the viewer at his/hers normal viewing position (= to be perceived as a sharp image). This comes from "2 minutes of arc" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_confusion - movie frames may be quite a bit blurrier due to the constant change, if I'm not totally mistaken.

Comment: Another variable is the *display device* refresh rate. A high frame-rate on a slow display will look no better. Also, human perception depends on many factors, such as brightness. A dim light in darkness has high persistence, and will appear to leave a noticeable trail when moved. (Trivia: birds have *very* fast visual perception, and do not "see" images on a scanned CRT display, though they do on LCD's.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know much about videos, but if my math is good, filesize should equal to bitrate times length.

That's correct.

> Image quality is hard to measure, but at fixed resolution, as a rule of thumb, the more bytes an individual pixel takes the better image quality, so it means larger filesize equals to better quality at fixed resolution.

For still images, yes, assuming the same compression algorithm. For a movie you still have the additional variable of framerate which will affect perceived quality.

> Now assume resolution is fixed, the size of each frame can be calculated by bitrate divided by framerate, so the filesize of the frame is directly proportional to bitrate and inversely proportional to framerate […]

That's assuming that all frames are made equal, which is not the case in video compression. Relatively few [key frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame#Video_compression) are stored in full. Most frames are represented as changes relatively to the previous frame because it's more space-efficient (because changes between frames usually aren't drastic).

> assume filesize is proportional to visual quality, this means framerate is inversely proportional to visual quality.

This is roughly correct, except the relationship won't be linear because you can't put key frames too sparsely (the link above explains why). But for most videos that should be a reasonably good approximation. I'd expect a bit different characteristics for extreme cases like ultra-slow-motion videos or video slideshows.

> So, at fixed bitrate and fixed resolution, does increasing framerate actually decrease image quality?

If you're talking about quality of stills, then yes. But that's not how humans perceive quality. For most content 720p at 30 fps is far more tolerable than 4K at 3 fps despite the number of pixels per second being roughly the same. That's because at 30 fps you get the intended illusion of motion. On the other hand if you're eg. recording slideshows, it will be a good idea to lower the framerate because there's no motion and it makes sense to budget more bytes to details in each frame.

Comment: I guess this explains why movies with higher resolutions tend to occupy more size with 1080p movies occupying Gigs of data on storage